# How to control the angle of ST_OrientedEnvelope() PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have some various polygons of non-uniform shape that I run ST_OrientedEnvelope() on as a first step for some further processing. In some cases I would like to force a certain angle that the envelope envelops the polygon at. Is there an efficient way to do this?

EDIT: The solution does not have to use ST_OrientedEnvelope(), just want to control angle of envelope somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotate the polygon first with ST_Rotate https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Rotate.html.

> Rotates geometry rotRadians counter-clockwise about the origin point.
> The rotation origin can be specified either as a POINT geometry, or as
> x and y coordinates. If the origin is not specified, the geometry is
> rotated about POINT(0 0).

Then you can create a normal envelope for the rotated polygon with ST_Envelope https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html.

Finally, rotate the newly created envelope backwards with ST_Rotate by the same amount than in step 1.

Comment: Ah genius! of course. thanks so much.

Comment: Could you update the question to mention that it does not have to be a solution involving ST_OrientedEnvelope? ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, `ST_OrientedEnvelope` "[returns the minimum-area rotated rectangle enclosing a geometry](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html)", i. e. the orientation of the result is based on the specific geometry passed to it without any way to influence it.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443736/14766), here's SQL implementing the **rotate-envelope-unrotate** approach:

```
WITH data(angle, geom) AS (VALUES
   (0.2, 'POLYGON ((10 60, 10 20, 50 30, 70 10, 90 60, 60 80, 40 60, 30 90, 10 60))'::geometry)
)
SELECT ST_Rotate( ST_Envelope(
                     ST_Rotate(geom, -angle, ST_Centroid(geom))),
        angle, ST_Centroid(geom)) AS envRot
    FROM data;
```

[image: Rotated Envelope of Polygon]

Comment: Nice example, thank you.